# Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с функцией js

Tags: javascript

Написать функцию, которая принимает случайный 
двумерный массив (разной длины) из 8 элементов. Функция 
возвращает тот массив сумма элементов которого 
наибольшая.

```
var arr = [
    [5, 3],
    [10, 16, 25, 42],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [151, 2, 84, 4, 69],
    [99, 111, 22, 166],
    [18, 36, 48, 64, 25, 56, 1, 15, 3],
    [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 46, 15, 5]
];

function recoverySum(arr) {
    var max = 0;
    var newarr = [];
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {

        var result = arr[i].reduce(function (sum, current) {
            return sum + current;

        })
        newarr.push(result);
        if (newarr[i] > max) {
            max = newarr[i];
        }
    }
    return arr[i];
}
document.write(recoverySum(arr));
```

Почему появляется такая ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined at recoverySum?

Comment: `i < arr.length`

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка появляется из-за неправильного условия цикла `i <= 8;`.

```js
var arr = [
    [5, 3],
    [10, 16, 25, 42],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [151, 2, 84, 4, 69],
    [99, 111, 22, 166],
    [18, 36, 48, 64, 25, 56, 1, 15, 3],
    [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 46, 15, 5]
];

function recoverySum(arr) {
  var max;
  var res;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var sum = arr[i].reduce(function (sum, current) {
      return sum + current;
    }, 0);
    max = i? max : sum;
    if (sum > max) {
      res = arr[i];
      max = sum;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(recoverySum(arr)));
```

Comment: Даже с arr.length не работает

Comment: @Алина Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```js
var arr = [
    [5, 3],
    [10, 16, 25, 42],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [151, 2, 84, 4, 69],
    [99, 111, 22, 166],
    [18, 36, 48, 64, 25, 56, 1, 15, 3],
    [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    [0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 46, 15, 5]
];

let d = arr.map(i => i.reduce((p, c) => p + c), 0);

console.log(arr[d.indexOf(Math.max(...d))]);
```

Comment: Поясните, за что минус?

Comment: за компанию *(4 символа нужно...)*